# Does Azure has dynamic file storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files

I'm looking at Azure storage offers and can't find file storage that grow as we go, one that it's not limited up front. Any idea if they have any service or a good way to achieve this "unlimited" file storage ?

Comment: What do you consider "unlimited"? Azure storage (blobs) provide up to 500TB per account. Azure File Storage (SMB on top of Azure Storage) provides up to 5TB per volume. Other than that, not clear what, exactly, you're asking.

Comment: So I have about 12TB of data and I wish to access all the data just like it's one huge disc. In case I use 3 volumes of 5TB I will need to "combine" them all together, virtually. I've done something like that using mhddfs, but it's getting slow/stuck from time to time.

Comment: Not exactly - the 5TB volumes are SMB shares (not something you'd combine). You'd need to mount 1TB disks and then stripe those into a large volume (2 mounted disks per core, so... up to 64 1TB drives possible).

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking at Blob or File storage, the limits are very high and not predetermined.  If you need Disk Storage, then there are preset limits but that is a more specialized scenario.  Blob is 500TB per container and 5TB per blob and File is 5TB per file share.

Here are the limits for blob and file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits

Comment: There is no per-container limit - the 500TB limit is per storage account.

Comment: I guess that is true, but the 500TB limit does apply in both cases. The page I references does show "Max size of a single blob container, table, or queue" as 500TB, so that is what I looking at.  You're right of course that the limit is 500TB for the whole account.  Given you position at MS, I will defer to your comment. :)  That said, I'm not sure my answer merits a downvote.

Comment: Downvote was cast when it was just a link and no details. I can't un-downvote unless question is edited (too much time has passed).